# How to dynamically insert data to a database from an array of objects using JavaScript and SQL

Tags: javascript, sql, node.js, reactjs, postgresql

I'll try and keep this as simple as possible. I am building a dynamic form that a client can fill out, and submit the data to a database (PostgreSQL). The front end is built with React and back end is with NodeJs. This question pertains to the server code.

After client fills out the form, their inputs get put into an array of objects, like so:

`const array = [{name: 'Jack', age: 30}, {name:'Sally', age: 28}, {name: 'Zero', age: 0}]`

I should mention that the user can add as many objects to **array** as they wish from the form. So there is no limit on how many objects could be inside of **array**.

I need to take this array of objects, iterate through it, and properly POST the **name** and **age** and their corresponding values for each object into the database.

This is a chunk of the code I currently have that is not working.

In the browser's console, after attempting to "submit", I receive a `400 BAD REQUEST` error response.

```
app.post('/test-url', (req, res) => {

  const { array } = req.body;

  const insertDetailsSQL = '
    insert into "details" ("name", "age")
    values ($1, $2)
  ';

  array.map(event => {

    const insertDetailsParams = [event.name, event.age] 
    db.query (insertDetailsSQL, insertDetailsParams)
    .then(result => {
      const [newResult] = result.rows
  }

 const newDetails = { newResult };
 res.status(201).json(newDetails);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

This may not be the cause of your issue but I noticed some issues with your code,

1. because of the scope of the newResult variable it will be undefined when assigning to newDetails
2. If you plan to loop through the array and insert individually, you cant return a response for each loop through, maybe return a response after the loop